How to integrate .Net 4.5 applications with Key Vault using REST API
I have a few applications developed using .net framework 4.5, those required to fetch the keys and secrets from Azure Key vault. I have planned to use the REST API as the .Net framework 4.5 does not support Azure Key vault out of the box. As the applications are deployed in Azure VM and some could be on-prem VMs, hence there is a challenge to use the REST API from the application hosted in VMs.
I came across this MSFT document which shows get token using CURL and a few .Net code samples as well. In this there is a static IP address is there (169.254.169.254). What this IP address signifies? Can this particular IP address be used in the source code?
I tried to find a tutorial which shows how to integrate .Net 4.5 applications with Key Vault  using REST API but was unable to find anything.
Upgrading to higher version of .Net framework or .Net core is not an option because of various other complexities.

The IP address 169.254.169.254 is a special address for the Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS). It's used to retrieve information about the Azure VM instance, such as access tokens, which can be used to authenticate requests to services like Azure Key Vault. This IP address is only available inside Azure VMs.
Since your applications are deployed on both Azure VMs and on-premise VMs, this can be a challenge because 169.254.169.254 is only accessible from Azure VMs, not from external machines. For on-premise VMs, you should consider using other authentication methods like client secrets or certificates, which can be configured through Azure AD.
Here are the basic steps to retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault using the REST API:
Authentication: If the app is running on an Azure VM, you can use IMDS to obtain an OAuth 2.0 token from Azure AD. Otherwise, for on-premise VMs, you can use a client ID and client secret or a certificate.
Example of retrieving a token with curl:
curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net' -H Metadata:true

Requesting secrets: Once you have the token, you can make a REST request to access secrets from Azure Key Vault.
Example of a request using the token:
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://<your-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/secrets/<secret-name>?api-version=7.0

If you are looking for examples of integrating Azure Key Vault with a .NET 4.5 application, unfortunately, .NET Framework 4.5 doesn't have built-in support for Azure Key Vault. However, you can manually make HTTP requests to Azure Key Vault's REST API using classes like HttpClient in .NET.

Thanks for the information. Is it safe and secure to use the IP address (169.254.169.254)? I didn't find any MSFT official document which shows this IP address is secure to be used for the Azure VMs.. Also, what could be the best practice considering security ?

The IP address 169.254.169.254 is a link-local address commonly used for communication between devices on the same local network without requiring a DHCP server. In the context of Azure, this address is used to access the metadata service for Azure VMs.
Security of Using 169.254.169.254
Limited Access: The address is accessible only from the VMs themselves. This means it cannot be reached from the internet or other networks, which is a positive aspect for security.
Sensitive Information: Accessing the metadata endpoint can retrieve sensitive information, such as credentials and access tokens. Therefore, it is crucial to handle this data carefully.
Best Practices for Security
Limit Access: Ensure that only authorized processes and users within the VM can access the metadata.
Use Managed Identities: Utilize managed identities for accessing Azure resources, reducing the need to manage credentials manually.
Monitoring and Logging: Implement monitoring and logging to track who accesses the metadata and when.
Updates and Patching: Keep the operating system and applications updated with the latest security patches.
Network Configuration: If possible, limit the exposure of the VMs to the internet by using Network Security Groups (NSGs) to filter incoming and outgoing traffic.
Documentation
Unfortunately, there does not appear to be detailed official documentation from Microsoft specifically regarding the use of the IP address 169.254.169.254 for Azure VMs. However, you can find general information about Azure VM metadata in the official Azure documentation, which explains how to use this endpoint to access instance metadata.

Thanks for the valuable information. In this statement “The address is accessible only from the VMs themselves”  , when you say “VM themselves “ ; do you mean “only Azure VMs” ?

Yes, in this case, “VMs themselves” specifically refers to each individual Azure VM instance. The metadata service at 169.254.169.254 is accessible only from within the same VM instance on Azure, meaning it’s isolated and can't be accessed by external entities, other Azure VMs, or machines outside Azure.
So, only the Azure VM on which the request is made can access its own metadata through this IP.

This answer looks like it was written by generative AI tools. It is worth knowing that such tools are not permitted to be used on Stack Overflow, as it encourages a culture of copy-paste without human judgement of each step.

If needing to do this in code for Framework 4.5, then it's perhaps worth knowing there are a couple of deprecated nuget packages that should allow you do the job.

Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Note: Deprecated in MS parlance means no longer in development.
Provided you have Set up the Vault, registered an App in Azure-AD, and granted access to the vault from the app, then it should essentially be a case of requesting a key-secret from the vault, using the app-name, app-key and key-name.
